# Why can I still run "vim" in cmd and powershell without put the directory of vim in the list of environment variables on windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-windows, startup

I installed gvim 8.0 on Windows 10. And I find that there's no item about vim in the list of environment variables. Look at the pictures below. But I can still run "vim" and "gvim" in cmd and powershell **without** entering the Fully Qualified Name of vim or gvim. Why can I do this? How does Windows know where to find vim.exe and launch it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer! When I installed gvim80.exe, it created several *.bat files(such as vim.bat, gvim.bat ...) in C:\Windows. Since C:\Windows is in the list of PATH, I can run vim without its FQN.